# How to correct IndexError in pandas with iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with one column a list of files

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

df.head()

array_index       age                    number  
35                [24, 45, 73, ....]      4     ....
23                [65, 97, 72, ....]      2    
99                [84, 12, 35, ....]      1     ....
....              ....
```

The data is formatted as such: The 'age' column has a list of ages from a patient, and the 'array_index' is the index of the patient within each `age` list we would like to examine.

So, in order to retrieve the age of patient index '35', we must find the 35th item in the associated list of 'ages'. We do this by the following:

```
df_new = pd.Dataframe(
    { "patientAge": [row.age[row.array_index] for _, row in df.iterrows()]})
```

Now there is a column 'patientAge' which has the ages for all of these special patients.

Let's say we want to retrieve the patient in the next position (e.g. 36, 24, 100)

The code I would run is this:

```
df_new = pd.Dataframe(
    { "next_patientAge": [row.age[row.array_index + 1] for _, row in df.iterrows()]})
```

But this outputs an error.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is because we are trying to access index `100` when `99` is the last index.

So, I try

```
df_new = pd.Dataframe(
    { "next_patientAge": [row.age[row.array_index + 1] for _, row in df.iterrows() if df.array_index != 99]})
```

and I would deal with the `NaN` values later. However, this doesn't work:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How does one correct this IndexError using iterrows()?

Comment: Didn't you mean `row.array_index != 99` rather than `df.array_index != 99`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_new = pd.Dataframe(
    {"next_patientAge": [row.age[row.array_index + 1] for i, row in df.iterrows()
     if i != 99]})
```

Comment: Actually, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'age'`